# Extract Google Calendar data to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-apps-script, google-calendar

I'd like to extract events from Google Calendar for a dynamic range: from (today) to (today+28), giving me a 29 day range of data.

How can I specify that using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that

1. Calculates the startPeriod time, defined as the beginning of today, and the endPeriod, 28 days later.
2. Grabs the events using `getEvents` method.
3. Gets some properties of each event to list in the sheet; as an example, I pick StartTime, EndTime, and Title for each event.
4. Puts the array of selected properties in the currently active sheet.

```
function listEvents() {
  var id = "...";   // enter Calendar Id, found on its Settings page
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
  var startPeriod = new Date();
  startPeriod.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  var endPeriod = new Date(startPeriod);
  endPeriod.setDate(endPeriod.getDate() + 28);
  var events = cal.getEvents(startPeriod, endPeriod);

  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) { 
    output.push([events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getTitle()]);    
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```